# Changing bootstrap caret(color and position)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, caret

I want to change color of caret and make it not relative from input text, because it's hard to make it look good when it is.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two ways I have done this.  If you want this to affect all carets on your site (probably not preferred) then you could override the caret css class in you:

```
.caret{border-top:4px solid red;}
```

Another option is to create a custom class and add it to the caret in your markup

```
.red{border-top:4px solid red;}

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action<span class="caret red"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The original JSFiddle has been updated
http://jsfiddle.net/whoiskb/pE5mQ/

Comment: And what about positioning of caret ? How could I solve my problem ?

Comment: Also, I can't manage to make active nav-pill doesn't change color. Can't find corresponding attribute.

Comment: To change the active nav-pill color you would have to override the the active classes related to the pill.  You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/whoiskb/pE5mQ/

Comment: not sure where you would like to position the caret, so I am not sure what you are looking for there.

Comment: It's OK. I just made different classes for different dropdowns.

Comment: @DenMed - I've similar requirements. Can you please share your solution. Need the caret to point right when closed, and down when open.

Comment: @Uri, try jsfiddle. I just changed the color and forgot about it. I don't play with design anymore, so you need to experiment)

Comment: So, the essence of the solution is: change the **border-color** in the .caret{} style rules. The caret is not a character and therefore is not styled using the CSS-color property.

Comment: is this solution no longer works? in jsfiddle example there are no carets showing up at all...

Comment: yes, it's not working anymore! can you please re-share?

Comment: I just updated my original answer with more details about the implementation. I also fixed the JSFiddle working example.

Answer (score 8):

This works for Wordpress Bootstrap

```
// Caret color
.navbar .nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret {
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: if you want to edit the bootstrap.css instead of just adding on a new class to override it, like i did,  then this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Refer to this post: [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

For example, the standard "down" arrow provided by bootstrap uses the following style:

```
<span class="caret"></span>

.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 dotted;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

Here I have just transposed the borders a bit, and now it is an "up" arrow. The same approach can be done for right and left carets.

```
<span class="up_caret"></span>

.up_caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0 dotted;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are awesome, you gave me the fundamental styling of the caret, and was able to customize it exactly as I want... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way but it should work:

Add this to your stylesheet (CSS) after the Bootstrap include.

```
.btn-primary .caret, .btn-warning .caret, .btn-danger .caret, .btn-info .caret, .btn-success .caret, .btn-inverse .caret {

    border-top-color: red;

    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity:1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
And what about positioning of caret ? How could I solve my problem ?

Comment: Also, I can't manage to make active nav-pill doesn't change color. Can't find corresponding attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only change the color of the caret itself, not the size or position, some simple CSS works fine (This is Bootstrap 3.3.6 and Wordpress 4.5.2):

```
a span.caret {
  color: #666
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this simple solution to change the position of the caret.

```
//example of moving curser 20 pixels to the right
input { 
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change color is to configure bootstrap as you like on:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

For caret color change:
Dropdowns -> @dropdown-caret-color

then go to the bottom of the site and click "Compile & Download" to get your custom bootstrap version.

**But note @dropdown-caret-color is deprecated as of v3.1.0**