# ngStrap Dropdown template

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm pretty new to angular and I'm using angular strap to customize a dropdown button because I wanted some HTML formatting on the resulting dropdown options.

I've managed to successfully assign a template to the dropdown options, but now I want to also style the button itself with another template.

Because I wanted it to look from this:

[image: Old Button Style]

To this:

[image]

Is this possible?

This is how my HTML tag looks now:

```
<button class="form-control custom-select" data-html="1" ng-model="myModel" bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" data-template-url="dropdown.tpl.js"  bs-select></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for requires only some CSS. When your HTML is compiled, the ouput (what is displayed on the browser) is:

```
<button class="form-control custom-select"
        data-html="1
        ng-model="myModel"
        bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons"
        data-template-url="dropdown.tpl.js"
        bs-select>
   <!-- placeholder -->
   <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

You have to customize the text alignment of your button and also the shape and position of the caret (which is a bootstrap class that creates an arrow).

You can find some advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801325/changing-bootstrap-caretcolor-and-position).

**EDIT:**

To use your HTML, you can pass a caretHtml argument for bsSelect directive:

```
<button class="form-control custom-select"
        data-html="1
        ng-model="myModel"
        bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons"
        data-template-url="dropdown.tpl.js"
        data-caret-html="<span class='myClass'></span>"
        bs-select>
   <!-- placeholder -->
   <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

This solution is not in the doc of Angular Strap but caretHtml argument exists in the source code. Be careful it may be removed in future updates.

Comment: Hi. I'm aware of the css solution. Actually I've implemented that already. However, if I'm able to change the template for how the dropdown button is displayed, it would be much better, as I can assign my own classes and have more freedom with the layout.

Thanks for the answer, though. 

Cheers~!

Comment: Ok, use the caretHtml argument then (see my updated answer).

Comment: The updated answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!